# Import Excel outline (drill-down) structured data

Tags: excel, import-from-excel

Is it possible to import outlined data from Excel?

This is where Excel shows drill-down `[+] [-]`.

Reading from ODBC doesn't give parent/child info; neither does exporting to CSV; export to HTML gives this info via mso-outline-level styles, but 2007 version puts actual content into subfolder and users will be VERY confused trying to select an appropriate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up parsing .mht file exported from Excel, it has the required structure in form of tr tags and mso- attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 'Group and Outline' feature needs one column(or row) to know how to group rows, isn't it ?
Info about outline is stored in [object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb242389(office.12).aspx). So neither ODBC nor CSV allow you to read it. You should use COM api in older versions of Excel or new C# api in latest to get access to those informations.